# Dynamically wrapping image with anchor href

Tags: jquery, blogger

For all `img` elements with the class border, I want to wrap them with an anchor element that uses Blogger's `data:post.link` variable to link to a specific post.

I'm using some code that I found here, but it's not having any effect:

```
jQuery("img.border").wrap("<a expr:href='data:post.link'></a>");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: It's now adding the anchor, but it's not reading the `expr:href` properly, so I get an empty anchor with no attributes.

Comment: Have you tried adding them separately?   Like wrapping it and then trying to add the attribute `$('img.border a').attr('href', 'data:post.link');`

Comment: I didn't because this will put `data:post.link` directly into the href attribute, but I need to format it as `expr:href` for Blogger to add the URL dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aNode = $('<a>');
aNode.attr('expr:href', 'data:post.link');
$('img.border').wrap(aNode);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't test this because the Blogger template is in XHTML and expects a closing </a>. Gets annoying to work with.

Comment: Expressions $('<a>') and $('<a></a>') are the same, jQuery will construct valid enclosed tag.

Comment: Right, but Blogger validates my code as XHTML before jQuery constructs the output. It's really annoying.

Comment: How about `var aNode = $('<a></a>');`?

Comment: That works, in the sense that it adds the correct tag and attribute, but it appears that the script runs too late and literally outputs `<a expr:href="data:post.link">` instead of getting the URL from Blogger.

Comment: Try to add `var postlink="<data:post.link />"` at the beginig of script and change `aNode.attr('expr:href', 'data:post.link');` to `aNode.attr('expr:href', postlink);`.

Comment: I tried exactly what you wrote, but it had no effect. Then, I removed the brackets from the `postlink` value and unfortunately, it had the same effect as the original script.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it does what I asked for, but there's a separate issue where I'm using Blogger's variables and not populating as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
function wrapHandler() {
  return "<a expr:href='data:post.link'></a>";
}

$("img.border").wrap(wrapHandler);
```

I viewed the DOM after calling `wrapHandler` and it does add the correct wrapper. You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/hyygm9vv/

Comment: Thanks, but this gave me the same output as my original script. Ends up like this: `<a href><img class="border" src="..." /></a>`. Not sure if it's an issue with when the script runs and getting the URL from Blogger.